# Images being sent with mimetype 'image/png' instead of jpg

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg, mime-types

I have an image gallery that loads thumbnails dynamically using a php glob of images (jpegs) in a directory.

On one particular gallery, the thumbnails are loading with the header 'image/png' instead of 'image/jpeg' and showing up as 1x1 PNG images instead of the 370x370px full thumbnails they're supposed to be.

I have used the php gd library to generate the thumbnails and they work in 99% of other cases, just not this particular case.

I cannot discern any particular difference between these images and any others on the site, I really am stumped.

When the resource are viewed in chrome, the following is shown when looking at any of the images:

```
filename.jpg

Dimensions 1 × 1
File size 67 B
MIME type image/png
URL http://mydomain.com/img.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated as to why these images are being sent with a png mime type as opposed to jpeg.

This is the image resizer class I am using:

http://pastebin.com/mMwMTKSF

With the thumbnails being generated via load, resizeLong, crop and save methods (in that order).

I can only guess that the image types are wrong in the original images but I've even gone and manually made some thumbs in irfanview to no avail, they're still being sent as PNG's and I have no clue why...

I can paste any code as it's needed.

Comment: Is your script actually outputting a PNG file? Can you open one of the 67 byte images in a text editor and see if it's actually an error message?

Comment: I can't figure out of way downloading the images to try this...though that's a thought, it may be an error message, that's a good point, I'll try and have a look.

Comment: You should be able to download the "image" file via Chrome's resources tab

Comment: That's the strange thing - I can't! When I try and download it using the resources tab it just goes to the actual correct image! Here's what it looks like in the resource viewer: http://i.imgur.com/qmPrHFl.png

Comment: I managed to download the PNG file produced, no error code.

It's available here:

http://www.speedyshare.com/9wWx7/download.png and from what I can tell every single one is the same.

Comment: Hmm, it's definitely a PNG rather than an error message saved as a PNG. Have you checked the permissions on that image gallery's directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just figured it out. After AGES of puzzling - it's purely because I had an adblocker running on my browser and it was replacing the images with a 1x1px PNG.

The name of the gallery that I was using was 'Adverts' because it was showcasing some ads I'd done.

The more you know.

For anyone else encountering this strange phenomena, this is what was sent as the image instead:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

so that anyone who now types that into google will see this post and realise how silly they were.